# How to attach miscellaneous data to a discord.js slashcommand interaction with select menus?

Tags: discord, discord.js, command, bots

Using v14, I have the following scenario:

1. SlashCommand that when executed fetches data from an external api
2. The returned data, which looks something like: `[{name:'Bob',age:30,country:'us'},{name:'Jane',age:32,country:'fr'}, etc, etc]` I send in an interaction reply as `StringSelectMenuBuilder` options
3. The option values have a character limit, so I can't stringify them and use them for the value field
4. Basically when a channel user selects (multi-select menu) options, I want the command handler to take the selected raw data like `{name:'Bob',age:30,country:'us'}` and POST to a different external api

I suppose you don't want to be passing around all that data and I can't store it inside a `StringSelectMenuBuilder` anyway. If I set the option values as the index and pass that back to the command handler, is there a way I can access the original returned data array?

Comment: Are you trying to add the API response as a stringified json to the option value?

Comment: Yeah I tried to JSON.stringify but the option value has a character limit of 100 and some of the returned data can be a bit long.

Comment: Perhaps I'd suggest using a `Collection` to store select menu `values` as keys and stringified JSON as values, or might as well integrate a database

Comment: Ah yes! The `Collection()` on the client to store miscellaneous data worked. Thanks for the tip!